# Can't add useful information to existing question without getting more reputation

Tags: support, new-users, protected-questions, rep-requirement

There's [a question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/381103/is-there-a-windows-exe-that-does-nothing) that is protected and requires 10 reputation to add an answer to. It also requires 50 reputation to add a comment.

I only have 1 reputation, but I have very useful information to add. It's for the case that parameters will be appended to the command.

Do I have to wait until I get more reputation?
Or ask a new question (it will be slightly more specific) and answer that?
Or ask someone else to answer this for me?

Comment: You don't have to wait, you can take on other activities if you can. Answer other questions and/or suggest good quality edits to improve existings posts/tag wiki's. That will gain you the reputation you need to achieve what you want. With waiting nothing changes...

Comment: 10 points means that you just need 1 upvote on an answer. How hard can that be?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be that hard, seeing that I just got 10 rep here from asking this... But, I find it a bit wrong to answer questions for the sole reason of reputation.

Comment: @rene I believe his use of the word wait was exactly that meaning ... the contribution to that page will have to wait until he takes other actions to earn rep.

Answer (score 9):

Did you notice why it requires 10 reputation? Unfortunately, new users don't often contribute the best content. That particular question has attracted a lot of pretty bad content. [The mod who protected it](https://superuser.com/users/36744/oliver-salzburg) has been around for quite a long time (going on 4 years; he also has the 11th most reputation on the site ATM). I don't think you're in much of a position to judge the wisdom of his decision, even if you happen to have a revolutionary contribution to the question (I don't doubt that you might, FWIW).

If you hang around long enough, you'll see how much work there is to do in just managing the messes others create. New users are somewhat disproportionately responsible for this. Those of us who clean it up are volunteering our time. Please try to appreciate the importance of allocating that time efficiently. Sifting through several non-answers for one proverbial gold nugget is not efficient generally. That's effectively what you'd be asking of the site's users if they unprotected this question just for you.

If you believe what you have to say is important, do stick around and earn your voice on less sensitive topics. Surely there are some easier questions to answer if you can even contribute in a big way to a question that's already been answered (more than) 9 times over two years. If you answer well, you'll probably get your first upvote while your answer is still fresh. Notice that answering other unanswered questions is what the `protected` banner itself suggests. This suggestion is there thanks to a recent feature request that was completed (more specifically, thanks to Jon Ericson – send him an upvote!):
"[Can we do something more useful when new users land on a protected question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225920/246931)"

If you can't do that, you might get your reputation just about as quickly by finding some posts to edit. Five accepted edits will give you enough to answer, and 25 will give you enough to comment. Again, you might be surprised just how much content out there needs proofreading. Pay your respects to the site and do a little cleanup work with us, and we'll be happy to consider the new content you wish to add. That's how I understand the rep requirement. I don't see anything wrong from this perspective.

**Edit:** BTW, the association bonus for getting 200 rep on another site won't count toward the rep requirement for answering a protected question, which depends on rep gained specifically on that question's site. As my comments below indicate, this is news to me...Please see this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): 
[Improve "Protected Question" message with regard to rep gained through Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210481/246931)

Comment: I completely agree. However, I also sympathize with the OP. I've been a productive member of the SE network for years, but I don't live on the site. (No slander towards those who do - I appreciate the administration services they provide the community.) Thus I have little rep. I spend most of my time on the site of my expertise, but I have experience and interests in many fields. It's extremely frustrating when I'm reading another site, see a way I can contribute, join the site, only to be blocked because I have 1 rep on that site. I wish established users started on new sites with some rep.

Comment: As soon as you make it to 200 rep on any site, your association bonus will kick in: +100 rep everywhere! You don't have to live here to get to 200 somewhere, and as soon as you do, you can answer, comment, and upvote everywhere :)

Comment: Gee, that will be nice. Maybe when the semester is over I'll sit down and make a concerted effort for the last bit.

Comment: @TravisBemrose note that there are two types of 'blocked' - there is "you need 50 reputation" for a comment and there is the "you need 10 reputation **on this site**" for a protected question.  The later is to try to ensure that the person has some familiarity with the culture of the site (one up voted answer or 5 edits) to know what is meaningful to add to a protected question.  I'll also point out that since your last comment you appear to have > 200 rep on Math.SE which triggered a +100 everywhere (you can comment on any question on any SE site now).

Comment: Yes, I realize there are different blocks. **Holy Snap!** +1820 rep across all sites today when I logged in to view your comment (phone notified me to check). Yes, I got a stunning 80 rep yesterday, most of it on one question. Previously it'd have taken me months to earn that much. Good news, now I won't be frustrated when I join a new site to make a minor contribution, or vote up on an answer that helped me.

Comment: Irony: I recently got 50 rep on Physics for a total contribution to the site of a one sentence, one picture answer (it was a good picture from the Math site).  Despite contributing to English Language & Usage (arguably one of the least friendly sites) for a year and a half now, I've earned a measly 26 rep.